# Cannot invoke method toInteger() on null object

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have the following code in a separate groovy file from my Jenkinsfile. It's supposed to cancel old build jobs once a new one is fired off. It also checks for different branch names.

```
@NonCPS
def cancelPreviousBuilds() {
  def buildNumber = env.BUILD_NUMBER.toInteger()
  def currentJob = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME)
  def currentBranch = env.BRANCH_NAME // Branch value of the current build

  // Cancel old jobs that are from the same branch
  for (def build : currentJob.builds) {
    // parse out the branch name from each job
    param = (build.getFullDisplayName().tokenize('»')[2]).tokenize(" ")[0]
      if (build.isBuilding() && build.number < buildNumber && currentBranch == param) {
        build.doStop()
    }
  }
}
```

However, my code is failing on

`def buildNumber = env.BUILD_NUMBER.toInteger()`

The error from Jenkins says:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method toInteger() on null object

Can I not use `toInteger()` here? From echo'ing out `buildNumber` this is definitely pulling out the build number, so I am pretty sure it is not actually null.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to integer using `Integer.parseInt`:

```
def buildNumber = Integer.parseInt(env.BUILD_NUMBER)
```

Adding snippet of code which I modified:

```
def currentJob  = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME)
def buildNumber = Integer.parseInt(env.BUILD_NUMBER)
def jobBuilds   = currentJob.getBuilds()

jobBuilds.each{ build ->
// Your condition goes here
if (build.number < buildNumber ){
        build.doStop()
    }
}
```